# $product->getDisableAddToCart() magic method questions

Tags: ee-1.14, magic-getter

I've run into an issue where `$product->getDisableAddToCart()` is returning `bool(true)` for some products, but I can't find a declaration of that method, nor can I find an attribute `disable_add_to_cart` in `eav_attributes`.

The method is called in

- `app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\Controller\Abstract.php` line 103
- `app\code\core\Enterprise\CatalogPermissions\Model\Observer.php` line 323, 380, 540 (Enterprise 1.14.0.1)
- `app\code\core\Enterprise\Checkout\Model\Cart.php` line 1021 (Enterprise 1.14.0.1)

Can anyone tell me where this is defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is being set with a Magic Setter, so no actual method or attribute even exists. Just search the codebase for `$product->setDisableAddToCart()` to find all of the places where it is called.

Comment: You will notice this behaviour with many of the getter and setter functions in magento, it's actually common.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the event in `app/code/core/Enterprise/CatalogPermissions/etc/config.xml`

Event: `checkout_cart_save_before` : `enterprise_catalogpermissions`

Function name:

1. **`checkQuotePermissions()`**
2. **`_initPermissionsOnQuoteItems($quote)`** - Just can see the  line: `$item->setDisableAddToCart(true);`

Which will reflect to this line: `$quote->removeItem($quoteItem->getId());`